# C++: Compilar usando Batch

Tags: c++, batch, gcc

Estou usando o cmd para programar, e quero fazer um arquivo batch que automatize o processo de compilação. Eu quero que ele compile os arquivos usando o comando

```
g++ -c ./scr/Nome.cpp -o ./obj/Nome.o -std=c++1z
```

Isso deve ser feito para todos os arquivos `.cpp` que foram editados desde a última compilação (eu pensei em fazer um input, assim `Nome` seria o texto que o usuário digitou, o programa então só continuaria se o usuário entrar com uma linha vazia), e por fim e executar

```
cd obj
g++ Arq1.o Arq2.o -o ../a.exe
```

Colocando todos os arquivos da pasta obj ao invés de `Arq1.o Arq2.o`

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Recomendo utilizar o **CMake+NMake**. Fazer seu próprio arquivo de lote para verificar as alterações desde o último build não é nada simples e é algo que os _build systems_ fazem nativamente. Afinal é para isso que eles servem: construir software.

Comment: @FernandoSilveira Entendo. Não tenho costume de compilar por CLI, pois sempre usei IDEs

Comment: @FernandoSilveira Só uma pergunta, como posso fazer para debugar meu programa linha a linha, pois meu programa está entrando em loop infinito, mas não consigo achar onde

Comment: No `gdb` use o comando `break main` e depois `run`. Quando ele parar no _breakpoint_ (função `main`) você pode usar os comandos `n`, `s`, `fin` e `c` (`next`, `step`, `finish` e `continue`).

Answer (score 1):

Ja existe pronto uma ferramenta para essa e diversas outras automatizacoes de compilacoes.

A ferramenta se chama `make` e é vastamente usada no mundo GNU/Linux.

Aconselho seguir esse tutorial para aprender o basico do basico sobre a ferramenta consulte [AQUI](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2002/cmsc214/Tutorial/makefile.html).

Para ter uma ideia geral do que se trata o `make` veja [AQUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)).

Para aprofundamentos consulte [AQUI](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.pdf).